# How to select one record per partial key using SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Havin a schema of the form
`T(Att1, Att2)` where `Key = Att1, Att2`

s.t

```
Soy, Bean
Soy, Powder
Soy, Milk
Almond, Powder
Almond, Milk
```

I would like a query that selects only single row per left-key
e.g

```
Soy, Powder
Almond, Milk
```

It could be any record as long as they have the same left hand side key.
How do I do it? When I use LIMIT it selects only a single row per table and this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation comes to mind:

```
select att1, min(att2)
from t
group by att1;
```

Comment: hmm right. I was thinking of grouping, but then I was thinking of grouping + limit and it is not smth that I can use as far as I know. min is a good solution I think. Thanks!